# sql stored procedure with out duplicates name

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

How can I create a query to SELECT ALL DB WITHOUT duplicates

Like (old DB that is no longer in use c,f,g. basically if it does have eur and has an original name than it is relevant):

```
a
b
c
ceur
d
f
feur
g
geur
```

I need it to be like:

```
a
b
ceur
d
feur
geur
```

Many thanks...

Comment: What have you tried? What do you want? It's a bit unclear what you are asking...

Comment: I want to filter DB so it would select a table of all DB but without duplicates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELECT DISTINCT

is what you're looking for. See more [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/distinct-optimization.html).

For instance, let's say you have a table that contains the following rows:

name, city, address, country.

You now wish to get the countries that has been stored, without duplicates. Multiple people might come from the same country, and so the table would most likely have duplicate entries of that country.

How you achieve this is by using the SELECT DISTINCT.

Example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT country FROM table_name;
```

What this will do is retreive the country row without duplicates. That way, you can see which countries are actually stored in that table without duplicates.

If you have multiple databases (I don't know if that's what you were getting at), then you will need to perform a JOIN on the relevant tables, given you have access to them all. I would recommend doing a LEFT JOIN if you are to join more than just 1 extra table.

Example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT table_name.row_name, table_name.row_name2, table_name.row_name3
FROM table_name
LEFT JOIN table_name2 ON table_name.row_name = table_name2.row_name
LEFT JOIN table_name3 ON table_name2.row_name = table_name3.row_name
[...]
WHERE table.row_name = 'value';
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19831821)

Comment: yes, but it's to give conclusive answers to a question that's immensly vague. I have no schema, no nothing. All I can do is simply give the answer to how to get distinct (non-duplicate) values in an sql statement.

Comment: Provided an example.

Comment: I should really just stop providing answers to incomplete questions. All it does is give you downvotes. Shame really.

Comment: You don't even have the option to comment on OP's post for elaboration without having 50 rep.

Answer (score 0):

Can you  query information_schema.TABLES and distinct in the select, plus a predicate to filter out whatever you don't want?

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
select t.*
from t
where name like '%eur'
union all
select t.*
from t
where not like '%eur' and
      not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.name = concat(t.name, 'eur');
```